# How to use partial Fractions on $\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I started with $$\frac A x + \frac B{x^2 + 1}.$$ Do I then multiply and get $1=A(x^2 +1) + B(x)$ ? If so I don't know what to do after this.

Comment: Because of the $x^2+1$ it should be $\frac A x+\frac {B+Cx}{x^2+1}$

Comment: You need to start with $\frac{A}{x} + \frac{Bx+C}{x^2+1}$.

Comment: Thanks so if x is 0 I get A=1. I don't understand for B, does it need to be the same x=0 value because B would change depending on what I choose for x correct?

Comment: Thank you thank you that's where i'm going wrong Thomas!

Comment: So I come up with 1=A(x^2 + 1) +(B+Cx)(x). I'm still confused how to solve each. I know it is simple and from techniques of linear algebra but I'm not seeing it

Comment: what you have is an identity; not an equality. so you can put any value for $x.$ but choosing them carefully may help you finding the constants fast.

Comment: "because B would change depending on what I choose for x correct?" Not at all! The whole point is that the A,B,C hold for ALL x.

Answer (score 2):

Your partial fraction decomposition should be
$$\frac{A}{x}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)}$$
Then multiply by $x(x^2+1)$
$$A(x^2+1)+x(Bx+C)=1$$
Let $x=0$ to give:
$$A=1$$
Let $x=1$, then
$$(1+1)+(B+C)=1$$
$$2+B+C=1$$
$$ B+C=-1$$
Let $x=-1$
$$2-(-B+C)=1$$
$$-(-B+C)=-1$$
$$-B+C=1$$
Adding the two equations together gives
$$2C=0$$
so $C=0$ and $B=-1$.

Comment: so for solving B, why pick x=1 I'm not seeing that why not x=2?

Comment: 2 would work equally as well as 1. However with 1 the algebra is a lot simpler. You could have picked 7 or pi or 53343433 or whatever. The point is you just have to pick SOMETHING. Typically -1,0,1 are easiest.

Comment: ok got it now! thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)}=\frac A{x}+\frac {Bx+C}{x^2+1}$$
Since $x^2+1$ is irreducible.
I found $A=1,B=-1,C=0$